# Getting minimum index while ignoring element value in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, min

Say we have this array:

```
arr = [[3, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6]]
```

And we have this conditional:

```
arr = [[3, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6]]

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if (arr[i][0] === 3 && arr[i][1] === 4 || arr[i][0] === 3 && arr[i][1] === 5){
        console.log(i)
    }
}
```

There respective indexes would be `1` and `2`, which would display in the `console.log()` in sequential order.

How would I grab the minimum index (`1` in this case), specifically, from that?  I cannot store the numbers in an array due to my use case, so I need to establish the minimum within the loop.  And you can't really set a min number because you won't know which element index will be the smallest beforehand.

Is this possible or am I overthinking it hard?

Comment: Sounds like a good match for `findIndex`. It returns the index once the first result is found.

Comment: `i = arr.findIndex(a => a[0] === 3 && a[1] === 4 || a[0] === 3 && a[1] === 5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a variable outside the loop, then assign `i` to it and break the loop if the condition is true:

```js
arr = [[3, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6]]

var ind = 0

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if (arr[i][0] === 3 && arr[i][1] === 4 || arr[i][0] === 3 && arr[i][1] === 5){
        ind = i;
        break;
    }
}

console.log(ind)
```

Alternatively, you can use `Array.findIndex`:

```js
arr = [[3, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6]]

var ind = arr.findIndex(e => e[0] === 3 && e[1] === 4 || e[0] === 3 && e[1] === 5)

console.log(ind)
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple... Thanks a ton - this works perfectly.